# Sensing items on a printed page - suggested technologies to look at for on/off, true/false, etc. detection

Tags: sensor

We are developing a product where:

- a child holds an electronic stylus
- she uses it in conjunction with a book that has multiple choice questions
- when she touches the right answer, the stylus will give positive feedback
- when she touches the wrong answer, the stylus will give appropriate feedback

The way that we currently have implemented this is using conductive ink (black) and a conductivity sensor on the tip of the stylus. We already have a line of products based on this system.

The CORRECT answer has a 1/4" black dot next to it (printed with conductive ink).
The WRONG answer has a 1/4" black dot next to it (printed with normal ink).

---

THE CHALLENGE:
 - we're making a new system for younger kids
 - questions have PICTURE multiple choice answers (b/c younger kids want to touch the stylus to the PICTURE and not the black dot)
 - we want the printing technology to not obstruct the picture

Any ideas on a system here? We're aware of the Leapfrog stylus that reads a small pattern of dots on a page. This technology is too expensive for us.

I'm looking for a list of technologies to investigate for on/off, true/false detection.

Comment: The reverse side of the page could selectively have whole pictures backed by conductive ink and capacitance could be used. If the conductive ink is optically dark then you need to do something to avoid the big visual hint like laminate an opaque sheet behind it.

Comment: Screw the book and make this into a Android app instead. Then you don't even need a klunky stylus anymore.

Comment: Less $ at stake if the book falls in the bathtub, can be larger, lighter for uncoordinated hands, can be used unsupervised and I would recommend iOS before Android.

Comment: Good point about the stylus. If capacitive system is used the stylus could be replaced by finger.

Comment: Should I just ask about the conductive ink technology here to make it more specific? I'm actually hoping that this community will help with some technology suggestions that I may not be aware of. Can I ask for technologies to look into or will that still be too open ended?

Comment: @OlinLathrop - good suggestion...will definitely be 'easier' implementation-wise. However, we are trying to develop a more physical experience so we've made a conscious decision to not use a screen.

Comment: Reopened, but I hope you realize publicly searchable crowdsourcing of ideas might make developing a product very very economically unworthwhile.

Comment: Also, depending on how young the kids are, could a simple matte vs glossy picture work? Not to underestimate them, but the younger they are, the less likely they might notice a pattern like that, atleast for a book or three.

Comment: @Passerby - regarding the crowdsourcing of ideas, do you mean that anyone can 'take' the idea?

Comment: @milesmeow it's hard to patent an open idea. Since it's easily googleable, some patent holder or troll who even thinks you might somehow possibly be infringing on their extremely vague patent would have some easy to find proof, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Oh. Simple. Ultraviolet reactive ink. Stylus has a large hollow tip that has a small uv diode with visual sensor of some sort that won't work on just uv light reflecting. Since UV reactive ink glows in the visible range when uv is shined on it, a digital color sensor would work.

Hell, skip the electronics, and just use a uv flashlight or stylus with just a smd uv diode at the tip, turns on when pressed down, the kid sees the picture glow.

Comment: I'll expect my 2% royalties in the mail.

Comment: Didn't Questron do this in the '80s with an IR sensor?

Comment: @JohnU Actually that's a great solution (*with caveats*): UV-reactive clear inks with emission in the infrared + red part of the spectrum are available, so a tiny UV LED in the tip would cause the invisible ink to glow both visibly and in IR. A daylight-filtered IR sensor (Vishay, etc) will sense the IR, and the user can see the red glow. Now the catch: Most UV-reactive inks I can think of are not child safe, and we all know kids love chewing on things.

Comment: A very interesting suggestion...I'll have to look into this. Cost is a big issue, hopefully the ink and sensor is not expensive.